# Is there a way to restrict deletion/editing on the state (Odoo-12)

Tags: odoo-12

I'm working on a new project using eclipse (odoo-12) but there is a problem where I need to restrict the deletion and editing and make it allowed only on specific state

Example:
no deletion allowed if state in(Delivered,Retrieved)

I've tried sql constraints but I didn't know how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to overwrite unlink method

```py
from odoo.exceptions import UserError
from odoo import _
    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        if self.state in ['Delivered','Retrieved']:
            raise UserError(_('message'))
        return super(YourClass, self).unlink()
```